# Convert negative image to positive

Tags: java, c++, image

I have old negative films I have scanned onto my computer. I want to write a small program to convert the negative Images to its positive state.

I know there are several image editor applications out there which I can use to achieve this conversion, but I am researching on how to manipulate the pixels to convert them myself via a small app.

Can anyone give me a head start on this? Sample code if possible will also be much appreciated.

Comment: *"Can anyone give me a head start on this?"*  What have you got so far?  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  Have a look over the JavaDocs for [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and see if you can figure out where to start.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I just wrote up a working example. Given the following input image `img.png`.

[image: img.png]

The output will be a new image `invert-img.png` like

[image: invert-img.png]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class Convert
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        invertImage("img.png");
    }

    public static void invertImage(String imageName) {
        BufferedImage inputFile = null;
        try {
            inputFile = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < inputFile.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < inputFile.getHeight(); y++) {
                int rgba = inputFile.getRGB(x, y);
                Color col = new Color(rgba, true);
                col = new Color(255 - col.getRed(),
                                255 - col.getGreen(),
                                255 - col.getBlue());
                inputFile.setRGB(x, y, col.getRGB());
            }
        }

        try {
            File outputFile = new File("invert-"+imageName);
            ImageIO.write(inputFile, "png", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to create a monochrome image, you can alter the calculation of `col` to something like this:

```
int MONO_THRESHOLD = 368;
if (col.getRed() + col.getGreen() + col.getBlue() > MONO_THRESHOLD)
    col = new Color(255, 255, 255);
else
    col = new Color(0, 0, 0);
```

The above will give you the following image

[image: monochromic-img.png]

You can adjust `MONO_THRESHOLD` to get a more pleasing output. Increasing the number will make the pixel darker and vice versa.

Comment: This is wonderful.  Is there any way to make the images binary (two colours/black & white), preferably using similar code?

Comment: Do you mean grey scale? Yes, you can just edit the `new Color(...)` part. I'd suggest you set all values to `(col.getRed() + col.getGreen() + col.getBlue())/3`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Greyscale isn't what I was looking for - I am looking to be able to convert an image into just black and white (aka a binary/1-bit image).  The resulting image should appear as a white background with black elements upon it which lack most detail. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I don't think that RGB comes into it as it does not deal with R, G or B.  Thank you.

Comment: kba how can we add green toning to rgb pixels

Comment: Nice. Put it here http://tinybrain.de/1004506

Answer (score 4):

Try [LookupOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/LookupOp.html). Here is a [sample](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1013851&seqNum=6) from Filthy Rich Clients book.

Answer (score 3):

A head start it is, then. Assuming that you have access to each individual pixel in the negative image, and that each pixel has components RGB, obtain the RGB components of the original pixels like this:

```
int originalRed   = Math.abs( pixel.getRed( ) - 255 );
int originalGreen = Math.abs( pixel.getGreen( ) - 255 );
int originalBlue  = Math.abs( pixel.getBlue( ) - 255 );
// now build the original pixel using the RGB components
```

Doing the above for each pixel, you can obtain the original image by recreating it pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: abs is unnecessary. Just do `(0xFF - pixel.getRed())`

Comment: that's another way to do it, but I'm trying to keep things simple to understand

Comment: @Oscar: How is adding unnecessary complexity "keeping it simple"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what's simpler to understand: an `abs` of an integer subtraction, or a single subtraction, but involving an hexadecimal value, that forces you to be aware of the binary representation of an integer?

Comment: I agree that `255` would be better than `0xFF`.

Comment: On second thoughts, no I don't.  `0xFF` is better, because it's explicitly obvious that it's the maximum 8-bit value.