# Algorithm to convert film negative RGB to positive RGB

Tags: c++, colors, photo, data-conversion

Assuming I have a photographic film negative scanned as an RGB image, I'm trying to find an algorithm that will convert the color values to an RGB positive.

Due to the orange bias ( http://photo.net/learn/orange-negative-mask ) if I simply say redPositive = 255 - redNegative I get a final image that has a strong cyan tint to it, and is very washed out.  That means the answers given here: [Convert negative image to positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662349/convert-negative-image-to-positive) are *NOT* correct.

So how would I craft the following routine:

```
struct RGB
{
    unsigned byte red;
    unsigned byte green;
    unsigned byte blue;
};

void FilmNegativeToPositive(RGB const &negative, RGB &positive)
{
    // What goes here?
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you could provide images of a negative and what the correctly calculated positive of it would look like? I'm afraid that merely going to Google might not yield exactly the sort of negatives you're working with.

Comment: Take a "black" image (e.g. the bit before picture 1 - not the white ones where you loaded the film into the camera and exposted it to the light, but the black bits that are between shot 1 and the leader that you loaded into the film roller). Scan that, measure it's RGB value, and "add" [or invert  and "subtract", depending on which side of the conversion to negative you do it ] that to the existing values. Probably best to scan in 16-bit precision, as in 8-bit, you'll most likely lose about one third of the bits.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the problem is not the RGB conversion. The linked answers are correct in that sense, that it's just `255-value`. The problem is your data.

Comment: I just scanned a blank piece of film, and got the values 200, 150, 100 in R, G, B. So you may want to try subtracting that before inverting.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have data to test, but according to the link you gave, the negative is a mixture of cyan, magenta and yellow dyes that are impure:

> The yellow dye layer is the most pure. The magenta dye layer has a noticeable amount of yellow in it. The cyan dye layer has noticeable amounts of both yellow and magenta in it.

Therefore, you want to do something like this (untested pseudocode):

```
Let I_MY be the ratio of yellow impurity to pure magenta dye
Let I_CY be the ratio of yellow impurity to pure cyan dye
Let I_CM be the ratio of magenta impurity to pure cyan dye

Given R, G, B in [0, 255]
Convert to CMY:
  C = 1.0 - R/255.0
  M1 = 1.0 - G/255.0
  Y1 = 1.0 - B/255.0

Calculate the impurities in the cyan dye and remove them, since we assume no other dye has cyan impurities:
  M = M1 - I_CM×C
  Y2 = Y1 - I_CY×C

Now the amount of magenta dye is correct, so subtract its yellow impurity:
  Y = Y2 - I_MY×M

Convert the corrected CMY values back to RGB:
  R' = 255×(1.0-C)
  G' = 255×(1.0-M)
  B' = 255×(1.0-Y)
```

If it turns out there’s more complicated contamination than that, you get a linear algebra problem:

```
[   1 I_MC I_YC]   [C']   [C]
[I_CM    1 I_YM] × [M'] = [M]
[I_CY I_MY    1]   [Y']   [Y]
```

Where you want to solve for C', M', and Y', then convert back to the RGB color space.