# Is there an easy way to invert colors of an ImageView in Java

Tags: java, image, colors, javafx-8

I want to invert the colors of an ImageView of a MenuItem when it's hovered/selected (like the Text). Because currently when the MenuItem is hovered/selected its graphic is only barely visible:

[image: Menu]
[image: Menu (with hovered/selected MenuItem)]

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: look for all black pixels and turn them white; this should be quite easy if you only have monochrome icons; leave alpha pixels alone; or just create separate glyphs with photoshop and activate them on the selected/hover state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662349/convert-negative-image-to-positive .the solution should help

Comment: I tried to do something like this in the past, found that MenuItems don't support mouse/focus/key events. That's handled by the selectionModel of the ContextMenu/ListView/TableView (in JavaFX)