# With iText Reading an image signature stream/object..is black background and white foreground, how to reverse

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to read image objects from a PDF document. The image comes out as black background and white text.  How can I reverse that.  the image in the pdf, is white foreground and black background.

Here is the code, main piece for loading the image component

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;

public class MyImageRenderListener implements RenderListener {

    /**
     * The new document to which we've added a border rectangle.
     */
    protected String path = "";

    /**
     * Creates a RenderListener that will look for images.
     */
    public MyImageRenderListener(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#beginTextBlock()
     */
    public void beginTextBlock() {
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#endTextBlock()
     */
    public void endTextBlock() {
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#renderImage(
     *com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo)
     */
    public void renderImage(final ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        try {
            String filename;
            FileOutputStream os;
            PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
            PdfImageObject tmp = null;
            PdfName filter = (PdfName) image.get(PdfName.FILTER);

            ///
            PdfDictionary imageDictionary = image.getDictionary();
            // Try SMASK, SMASKINDATA
            PRStream maskStream = (PRStream) imageDictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.SMASK);

            // todo - required - black white - fix
            PdfImageObject maskImage = new PdfImageObject(maskStream);
            image = maskImage;
            if (PdfName.DCTDECODE.equals(filter)) {
                filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), "jpg");
                os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } else if (PdfName.JPXDECODE.equals(filter)) {
                filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), "jp2");
                os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } else if (PdfName.JBIG2DECODE.equals(filter)) {
                // ignore: filter not supported.
            } else {
                BufferedImage awtimage = renderInfo.getImage().getBufferedImage();
                if (awtimage != null) {
                    filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), "png");
                    ImageIO.write(awtimage, "png", new FileOutputStream(filename));
                }
            }

            try {
                final String newfile = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), ".x.", "png");

                BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
                BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
                newBi.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
                ImageIO.write(newBi, "png", new FileOutputStream(newfile));
            } catch(final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Image makeBlackAndWhitePng(PdfImageObject image) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
        BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
        newBi.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(newBi, "png", baos);
        return Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
    }

    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#renderText(
     *com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo)
     */
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    }
}
```

And code around loading the pages

```
 public static void readImages(final PdfReader reader, final File filex) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
            PdfObject pdfobj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
            if (pdfobj == null || !pdfobj.isStream()) {
                continue;
            }
            PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) pdfobj;
            PdfObject pdfsubtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
            if (pdfsubtype != null && pdfsubtype.toString().equals(PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {
                byte[] img = PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw((PRStream) stream);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filex.getParentFile(), String.format("%1$05d", i) + ".jpg"));
                out.write(img);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you see merely is the soft mask of the image which contains transparency information, white = opaque, black = transparent. The base image actually is all black but only where the mask indicates _opaque_, that image black is drawn. Thus it looks like revered.

Comment: How do I get my image to have a white background with the code above

Comment: Use image manipulation libraries. The image in your pdf does not have any white, it is completely black but a lot of it is completely transparent.

Comment: So I can use the java image library ... to reverse the colors?  I can see white on black but not the reverse

Comment: *"So I can use the java image library ... to reverse the colors?"* - I would expect so. It would be quite disappointing if that wasn't possible. Simply googl'ing for *"imageio invert image"* returns [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8662349/1729265), [this](https://dzone.com/articles/inverting-colour-images), and numerous other interesting matches.

Comment: Can someone add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To combine my comments:*

What you see, merely is the soft mask of the image which contains transparency information, white = opaque, black = transparent. The base image actually is all black but only where the mask indicates opaque, that image black is drawn. Thus it looks like reversed.

You can use image manipulation libraries to invert a bitmap. Simply googl'ing for "imageio invert image" returns [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8662349/1729265), [this](https://dzone.com/articles/inverting-colour-images), and numerous other interesting matches.